# How to get the sum in my collection in nested array?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this collection :

```
...
"votes": [
 {
   "track1": [
     {
       "facebook": NumberLong(1) 
    } 
  ],
   "track2": [
     {
       "google": NumberLong(1),
       "twitter": NumberLong(1) 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

],
    ...

I want to get the sum of the votes  of track1 or track2 so what i did is :

```
$match = array(
            'app_id' => (int)$appId,
            'campaign_id' => (int)$campaign_id
        );

        $group = array(
            '_id' => 'votes.0.'.$_t.'.0.facebook', //$_t => track id
            'total' => array(
                '$sum' => '$votes.0.'.$_t.'.0.facebook'
            )
        );

        $res = $collection->aggregate(array(
                array(
                    '$match' => $match
                ),
                array(
                    '$group' => $group
                )
            )
        );

        $res_facebook = (int) $res['result'][0]['total'];
```

Result : 0

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit. Its unclear where the app_id, campaign_id, $group, $match is coming from....!!

Comment: i used the app id and campaign id to find in my collection the right document and after that i want to get the sum of votes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, I didn't check it, but I had something similar.
This is how I would solve it:

```
$votes_array = json_decode($votes_array_json,TRUE);

$total_votes = 0;
foreach($votes_array as $track) {
    foreach($track as $social_network => $votes) {
          $total_votes = $total_votes + $votes;
    };
};
```